# probability of randomly drawing the same card from 2 decks at the same time? From 54 decks?

Tags: probability

What is the probability of randomly drawing the same card from 2 decks at the same time?  My math tells me 1:52 but my gut says I have a problem somewhere.

The same card from 54 decks?

Thanks!

Comment: For the first question, your math is fine.  Eat something to feed your gut.

Answer (score 1):

With the hidden assumed meaning of random and the hidden assumptions of independence, we are looking for the probability that the two cards drawn are the same. So, it's equal to the sum of all $P_{s,r}$ where $s$ runs over all suits and $r$ runs over all ranks. Since all these $P_{s,r}$ are equal (hidden assumption here), let's say to $p$, we have that the total probability is $p$ times the number of cards, i.e., $52\cdot p$. To find $p=P_{s,r}$ note that the probability of drawing the card $(s,r)$ from each deck is $\frac{1}{52}$ (hidden assumption) and by the (other hidden) assumption of independence, the probability of both cards being $(s,r)$ is $\frac{1}{52}\cdot \frac{1}{52}$. Thus, to conclude, the desired probability is $\frac{1}{52}$. (Intuitively, the choice of the card from the first deck does not matter, once it's chosen the only question is what is the probability that the other card from the second deck will be *that* card.)

Can you now asnwer the second question?

Comment: How guys are great!  Thanks for the response.  I have a masters from Georgia Tech but, unfortunately, it is in architecture, not math.  Can I answer the second question?  Not with confidence.  Intuitively, to me, p is always 1/52 regardless of how many decks you have.  But, if I take 1000 decks and draw a card from each, I can't see drawing the same card, from all decks, 1 in 52 draws. No, I can't answer the second part.  Can you please help?

Answer (score 0):

**Hints**:

1. How many possible pairs of cards can you draw when you draw 2 cards from 2 decks?
2. Of the combinations in point 1, how many pairs will have identical cards?

Answer (score 0):

For the second question.

If by "the same card from $54$ decks" you mean one card $54$ times the probability is tiny: first card can be anything; then you have to match it $53$ times, with probability $(1/52)^{53} = 1.2 \times 10^{-91}$.

If you mean "some pair of cards matches" then you're sure to have a match since there are just $52$ possible choices for $54$ cards. This is the [pigeonhole principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle). For smaller number of decks the probability increases toward $1$ faster than you might think: it's a version of the [birthday problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem).

Answer (score 0):

Well that's an interesting question. I am not sure this is what you mean, but I will put in more explicit terms the problem you have:

1. You have 2 decks of cards, each deck having 54 cards, all different
   from each other (you know, 2 regular card decks).
2. You shuffle both of them.
3. You draw one card at a time from both cards, and check if the drawn cards are the same.

Meaning that, after shuffling, you will have two sequences of cards. Let us call those two sequences *m* and *n*. So, what we want to know is the probability of

∃*x*∈{1,2,...,52}: *m*[*x*] = *n*[*x*]

being true. It translates as: "There exists at least one value of *x* between 1 and 52, such that the *x*th element of *m* is equal to the *x*th element of *n*"

So, for a start, pick whatever value of *x* you'd like. Then, identify what is the value of *m*[*x*]. Now, we know there is a $\frac{1}{52}$ chance that *n*[*x*] is the same as *m*[*x*], which is the same to say that there is a $\frac{51}{52}$ chance that *n*[*x*] is ***not*** the same as *m*[*x*].

There are 52 values of *x* you could have possibly chosen to analyse. Therefore, there should be a probability of $(\frac{51}{52})^{52}$ that, for all 52 values of *x*, *n*[*x*] is ***not*** the same as *m*[*x*].

$(\frac{51}{52})^{52}$ is approximately 36.43135%. So if there is a 36.43135% chance that there is not a single pair of equal cards, then there is a 100% - 36.43135% = 63.56865% probability that there is ***at least*** one pair of equal cards.

Based on simple logics, people assume the chance that there is at least one pair of equal cards in 2 shuffled decks is significantly low. That's also why people are often surprised when it is empirically shown that such fenomenon happens a lot more frequently than expected.